# How to convert string to bytes8 in solidity?

Tags: string, byte, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I get string parameter in the function, and the length of the parameter is less than 8.
and I want to convert this parameter to bytes8 for saving in the array.
How to convert it?

for example :

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;
contract MyContract{
    bytes8 [] Names;
    
    function setName(string memory _name) public{
        Names.push(_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your function code, pls. there are tons of packages

Comment: @yilmaz ok. i edit post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code in `solidity 0.8.7` works

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;
contract MyContract{
    bytes8 [] Names;
    
    function setName(string memory _name) public{
        // convert string to bytes first
        // then convert to bytes8
        bytes8 newName=bytes8(bytes(_name));
        Names.push(newName);
    }
}
```

Or in solidity you could pass bytes8 as argument

```
function setName(bytes8 _name) public{
        Names.push(_name);
    }
```

when you call this in front end, you convert the string to bytes8 and then pass it as argument